# Emacs C++-mode incorrect indentation?

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

I'm running emacs 23 with c++-mode and having some indentation problems.
Suppose I have this code:

```
void foo()
{
   if (cond)
     { <---
        int i;
        ...
     } <---
}
```

This seems to be the default behavior of the automatic indentation.
However I'd like to change it so it'll be like this:

```
void foo()
{
   if (cond)
   {
      int i;
      ...
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do this easily by configuring c++ mode or my .emacs file?

Comment: Check out the <a href="http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC#toc2">Emacs wiki on Indenting C</a>

Comment: For the record, this indentation mode is the GNU style. All GNU programs are required to follow this indentation style.

Comment: yeah I read that somewhere, but I can't stand it

Comment: It's generally good practice to code for your users, not yourself.  Most people not writing GNU code use other styles.

Answer (score 44):

I have the following in my .emacs file:

```lisp
(defun my-c++-mode-hook ()
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)
  (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c++-mode-hook)
```

You can determine which offset to edit by hitting [ctrl-c ctrl-s] on any line.   On the first line with a brace after the `if` it will say `substatement-open`.

Answer (score 26):

This is mine... this matches the default setup for visual studio.

```lisp
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
 ;; my customizations for all of c-mode, c++-mode, objc-mode, java-mode
 (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0)
 ;; other customizations can go here

 (setq c++-tab-always-indent t)
 (setq c-basic-offset 4)                  ;; Default is 2
 (setq c-indent-level 4)                  ;; Default is 2

 (setq tab-stop-list '(4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 52 56 60))
 (setq tab-width 4)
 (setq indent-tabs-mode t)  ; use spaces only if nil
 )

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking for this everywhere... For as long as I can remember.

Comment: (setq c-default-style "bsd" c-basic-offset 4)
Accomplishes a lot of that in less lines. Although the indent-tab-modes should stay.

Comment: I can't get anything to work -- this is driving me mad -- curly braces still indent inside if-statements.

Comment: That's strange. When you are in a c file do you see the variable `c-mode-common-hook` overridden?

Answer (score 13):

Short answer: Put this line into your `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0)
```

Long answer: ...

For those of us who are new to emacs-lisp, there is a pretty simple method at [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?(efaq)Customizing%20C%20and%20C%2B%2B%20indentation):

- Go to the line you want to indent
- Type C-C C-O  (that's the letter "O", not zero)
- Press *Enter* to accept the default suggestion
- Type "0" (that's a zero) for no extra indentation, press *Enter*
- Type *Tab* to reindent the line.
- Future "{" in this situation will have the correct tab setting, until you restart emacs.

The nice thing about this method, is that you can actually *see* the lisp code that you want to change. You can put in your .emacs file:

```lisp
(c-set-offset 'SYNTACTIC-SYMBOL OFFSET)
```

Additionally, you may want to check out the program [AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) to automatically format C++ source outside of emacs.

Comment: This seems to be the most convenient approach, but is there a way to define a style that incorporates all your changes?

Comment: It's a bit late, but I must say this is the neatest way to customize the indentation and very straightforward. I like the **Long Answer** part.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is actually wrong. Emacswiki won't help.

Insert following code into `~/.emacs`:

```lisp
(defun fix-c-indent-offset-according-to-syntax-context (key val)
  ;; remove the old element
  (setq c-offsets-alist (delq (assoc key c-offsets-alist) c-offsets-alist))
  ;; new value
  (add-to-list 'c-offsets-alist (cons key val)))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (derived-mode-p 'c-mode 'c++-mode 'java-mode)
              ;; indent
              (fix-c-indent-offset-according-to-syntax-context 'substatement-open 0))
            ))
```

See http://blog.binchen.org/posts/ccjava-code-indentation-in-emacs.html for technical details.

The key issue is c-set-offset is **not reliable** to detect syntax context any more (Emacs24.3.1). So the only reliable way is to analyze the original emacs code. The detailed steps to hack the code is listed in my article, basically you need read the function **c-indent-line** which is defined in /usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/progmodes/cc-cmds.el

Some people complained that my setup does not work. Actually it works in all **stable** versions of Emacs (23.4, 24.3, 24.4) if you don't change default setup (The indention has different profiles, my setup is based on default profile).

My key point is, on this specific issue, you need read the code.

Answer (score 1):

Before tuning individual offsets, configure preferable style. I use stroustrup, you my try some others, see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC#toc1 for names and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant:_Stroustrup for examples

M-x customize-variable c-default-style
(and set your preferred for C++_