# How does the following statement is interpreted by emacs

Tags: emacs

https://stackoverflow.com/a/663636/391104

```
(defun my-c++-mode-hook ()
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)
  (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c++-mode-hook)
```

Based on my investigation, I just need to add the above code into my .emacs and then it works magically.

Q1> What does `defun my-c++-mode-hook ()` mean? a function definition in lisp?

Q2> What is the usage of following line? where should I trigger it or it is run automatically by emacs

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c++-mode-hook)
```

Thank you

Comment: These are basic Elisp constructs. I suggest you look at the doc strings in Emacs with `C-h f` near the function calls e.g. `add-hook`, `defun` etc; and `C-h v` near the variables e.g. `c-basic-offset` etc. It would also help if you consulted the [Emacs Lisp Intro](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/index.html) book. This is also available from within Emacs as an Info page. GL

Answer (score 5):

Q1: Yes, this is a function definition (hence `defun`). The second symbol is the name, which has the suffix '-hook' to indicate to humans that it is intended to be used as a hook. It could be given (almost) any arbitrary name without changing its behaviour. The empty `()` indicates the function takes no arguments. Everything else is the body of the function.

Q2: Basically, this adds a pointer to the previous function to the list of functions that are called when ever `c++-mode` is started. Whenever you start a mode, the Emacs looks for the mode hook, running all the functions in it. Both the function definition and the add-hook line need to go in your .emacs, and they will be run automatically when you start emacs.

To wrap your head around elisp, the introduction is highly recommended. It ships with emacs, and can be accessed from the info system: `C-h i`, then look for Elisp Introduction.