# emacs C++ enter indention set to 4 space

Tags: c++, emacs

When I write C++ code in emacs, there is a problem:

```
template <typename ROLE_BASIC_ARRAY, typename Index0T,  
..........typename Index1T = NullIndex1<typename
```

but I want to indent like this:

```
template <typename ROLE_BASIC_ARRAY, typename Index0T, 
....typename Index1T = NullIndex1<typename
```

How can I configure my emacs ? thanks.

Comment: Lots of results for [emacs c++ indentation](https://www.google.com/search?q=emacs+c%2B%2B+indentation&oq=emacs+c%2B%2B+indentation&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4568j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), including StackOverflow questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs C++-mode incorrect indentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663588/emacs-c-mode-incorrect-indentation)

Comment: @crashmstr lots of non-working solutions offered on all those SO questions, which brings me here... although methinks the problem is with emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done used code:

```lisp
(c-add-style "microsoft"
          '("stroustrup"
            (c-offsets-alist
             (innamespace . -)
             (inline-open . 0)
             (inher-cont . c-lineup-multi-inher)
             (arglist-cont-nonempty . +)
             (template-args-cont . +))))
(setq c-default-style "microsoft")
```

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you should do it

```lisp
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4)
```

Reference: 
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC

Comment: This does not work on emacs 26.4 on Win10 64.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to reload the buffer first