# set default indent in emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, coding-style, indentation

I'm trying to set the default value for the number of spaces that gets used to indent lines in C++ mode. I see a lot of answers and have tried a setting a few things (in my `~/.emacs.d`):

```
(setq c-basic-offset 2)
```

In a completely separate attempt, I tried the following:

```
(setq-default c-basic-offset 2)
```

In both cases, if I use `C-h v` to test the value of the variable I get

```
Its value is 4                                                                       
Original value was set-from-style                                                     
Local in buffer file.cc; global value is 2
```

I interpret this to mean that one of the minor-modes (I suspect the value of `c-indentation-style`) is overwriting the global value. So instead I set the value as follows:

```
(setq c-default-style "bsd"
  c-basic-offset 2)
```

When I try to query the value of the variable I still get an output similar to above. I am able to manually set the value of the variable for buffers and it seems to work fine. Does anyone have any ideas about what I should do to make it more "permanent"?

Comment: Add buffer-local settings to the mode hook -- see the following link for a variety of examples:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663588/emacs-c-mode-incorrect-indentation

Comment: Thanks! This mode hook fixed my problem: `(defun my-mode-hook() (setq c-basic-offset 2) )`