# When writing C++ in Emacs, why does it seemingly randomly indent in the middle of lines?

Tags: c++, emacs

I'm writing a C++ program in Emacs, and I've encountered an irritating feature whereby when I type one of a set of seemingly random characters, it will indent the line I'm typing on.

For example:

`cout<<"Case #"<<case<<": ";`

Each time I typed the `<<` operator, the line would be indented by two spaces, which I would then have to go back and remove. The same thing would occur when typing `(`. After a while, you start to get bored of this. Any idea why this might be happening?

The only style point I've changed from default is to set the 'style' variable to 'linux', and all I've got in my `~/.emacs` is:

`(setq backup-directory-alist (("." . "~/.saves")))
 (setq tab-width 4)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emacs C++-mode incorrect indentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663588/emacs-c-mode-incorrect-indentation)

Comment: You may have a mismatch earlier in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle electric indentation on/off with `c-toggle-electric-state` (eg `M-x` ...).  When turned off you shouldn't get an automatic indentation after typing `<<` or `(`.

If you always want it off, it can be turned off in your `c++-mode-hook`, eg

```
(defun my-c++-mode-hook ()
  ;; ...
  (c-toggle-electric-state -1))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c++-mode-hook)
```