# Custom 4-space indentation in the ./emacs.d/init.ls file is performed with 8 spaces

Tags: emacs, indentation, dot-emacs

I wanted to configure my emacs settings, so as it is said in emacsWIKI I edited `.emacs.d/init.el` (the file didn't exist so I created a new one).

In the file I wrote:

```
(setq tab-width 4) ;; For changing identation to four spaces.
(defvaralias 'c-basic-offset 'tab-width) ;; For applying the changed identation to C files.
(global-display-line-numbers-mode) ;; For showing absolute line numbers.
(setq column-number-mode t) ;; For showing column numbers.
```

However, although I changed the identation to 4 spaces emacs writes 8. (The other two lines work instead).

Do you know what this is due to?

[I followed this guide](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentationBasics)

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using GNU Emacs 27.1

Comment: [Hi there, I found the answer to my problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663588/emacs-c-mode-incorrect-indentation)